# How to insert a text into the GuiOkCodeField using SapGuiLibrary from Robot Framework?

Tags: robotframework, sap-gui

I'm using the SapGuiLibrary with Robot Framework and I'm trying to insert a text into the GuiOkCodeField. I've tried the *Insert Text* command but it didn't work as you can see below.

```
    *** Settings ****
Library     Process
Library     SapGuiLibrary
Variables   ../Data/SAP.py

*** Test Cases ***
Conect SAP GUI
  Start Process      ${Winium}
  Start Process      ${Saplogon}
  Wait Until Keyword Succeeds    30s    1s    Connect To Session
  Open Connection    ${Con_Name}
  Input Text         ${GuiOkCodeField}    Fbl1n
```

When I ran this code the log message was: *ValueError: Cannot use keyword 'input text' for element type 'GuiOkCodeField'*

So I don't know how to send a text value to this field. Any suggestion?

Comment: Shouldn't you use `run transaction fbl1n` instead of `input text ${GuiOkCodeField} Fbl1n`?

Comment: You're completely right @SandraRossi. Thank you very much, I was think with a Selenium mind. Thank you to open my eyes. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have converted my comment into an answer. Feel free to complete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run a transaction code on SAP GUI for Windows with Robot Framework, use :

```
run transaction fbl1n
```

More information about keywords for SapGuiLibrary: https://frankvanderkuur.github.io/SapGuiLibrary.html